# How to integrate lync with a windows form application

Tags: .net, winforms, integration, lync

I have an application written in .net winforms.

There is a form that shows the author of the document, I am required to add the Lync presence orb next to the authors name.

The same as the one you can see in Outlook when add a contact to an email.

Is there a prebuilt winforms control for this presence orb?

Comment: I have found the answer, tho I am unable to post it for another 5 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft have made available a set of WPF controls that make it very easy to add things like presence into existing applications. I blogged about it last week here: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/05/microsoft-lyncs-development-secret-its-easy/

However, this is only for Silverlight and WPF. If you're developing in classic WinForms, it's possible to host WPF controls within a WinForms app: MSDN has information on doing this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx), and there's a good walk-through [here](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-add-wpf-controls-in-simple-windows-forms/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a WPF control called [Presence Indicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378628.aspx).
You have to use the [ElementHost object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to embed it in a standard WinForms Application.

A code snippet showing what worked for me.

```
public TestForm()
{
    ElementHost lyncHost;
    lyncHost = new ElementHost();
    this.Controls.Add(lyncHost);
    PresenceIndicator lyncControl = new PresenceIndicator();
    lyncControl.Source = "sip:j.smith@example.com";
    lyncHost.Child = lyncControl;
}
```